# "React.Children.only expected to receive a single React element child" error when putting <Image> and <TouchableHighlight> in a <View>

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native

I have the following render method in my React Native code:

```js
render() {
    const {height, width} = Dimensions.get('window');
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Image 
          style={{
            height:height,
            width:width,
          }}
          source={require('image!foo')}
          resizeMode='cover' 
        />
        <TouchableHighlight style={styles.button}/>
      </View>
    );
  }
```

It gives me this error:

> `React.Children.only` expected to receive a single React element child

If I remove the `TouchableHighlight` component, it works fine. If I remove the Image component, it still gives that error.

I can't see why it gives me this error. `<View>` should be able to have more than one component inside it for rendering.

Answer (score 158, accepted):

It seems that `<TouchableHighlight>` must have exactly one child. The docs say that it supports only one child and more than one must be wrapped in a `<View>`, but not that it must have at least (and most) one child. I just wanted to have a plain coloured button with no text/image, so I didn't deem it necessary to add a child.

I'll try to update the docs to indicate this.

Comment: Interestingly, the analogous `<TouchableOpacity>` doesn't apply such a one-child policy (shrugs)

Answer (score 36):

The `<TouchableHighlight>` element is the source of the error. The `<TouchableHighlight>` element [must have a child element](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/touchablehighlight.html).

Try running the code like this:

```js
render() {
    const {height, width} = Dimensions.get('window');
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Image 
                style={{
                    height:height,
                    width:width,
                }}
                source={require('image!foo')}
                resizeMode='cover' 
            />
            <TouchableHighlight style={styles.button}>
                <Text> This text is the target to be highlighted </Text>
            </TouchableHighlight>
        </View>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 20):

Yes, indeed you need to have one child inside your `<TouchableHighlight>`.

And, If you don't want to pollute your file with `Views` you can use React [Fragments](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html) to achieve the same.

```js
<TouchableWithoutFeedback>
  <React.Fragment>
   ...
  </React.Fragment>
</TouchableWithoutFeedback>
```

or even better there is a [short syntax](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html#short-syntax) for React Fragments. So the above code can be written as below:

```js
<TouchableWithoutFeedback>
  <>
   ...
  </>
</TouchableWithoutFeedback>
```

Answer (score 4):

I had this same error, even when I only had one child under the `TouchableHighlight`. The issue was that I had a few others commented out but incorrectly. Make sure you are commenting out appropriately: http://wesbos.com/react-jsx-comments/

Answer (score 3):

just after `TouchableWithoutFeedback` or `<TouchableHighlight>` insert a `<View>` this way you won't get this error. why is that then @Pedram answer or other answers explains enough.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I just had to put the element one line down:

This throws an error:

```js
export function DismissKeyboard(props: IProps) {
  return <TouchableWithoutFeedback
    onPress={() => Keyboard.dismiss()}> {props.children}
  </TouchableWithoutFeedback>;
}
```

While this does not throw an error:

```js
export function DismissKeyboard(props: IProps) {
  return <TouchableWithoutFeedback
    onPress={() => Keyboard.dismiss()}>
    {props.children}
  </TouchableWithoutFeedback>;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I also used same solution from following article and it throwed this error:
https://akshay-s-somkuwar.medium.com/dismiss-hide-keyboard-on-tap-outside-of-textinput-react-native-b94016f35ff0

Answer (score 2):

Usually it happen in TochableHighlight. Anyway error mean that **you must used single element inside the whatever component.**

**Solution :** You can use single **view** inside parent and anything can be used inside that View.  *See the attached picture*

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jI9OS.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please don't use images of text to describe something that could easily be typed and then formatted using the markdown facility that's available to you.

Answer (score 1):

1. `<TouchableHighlight>` element can have only one child inside
2. Make sure that you have imported Image

Answer (score 0):

use `TouchableHighlight` from '`react-native-gesture-handler`' instead of '`react-native`'

```
import { TouchableHighlight } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
```

The description from the documentation says:

> Gesture Handler library provides an implementation of RN's touchable
> components that are based on native buttons and does not rely on JS
> responder system utilized by RN. Our touchable implementation follows
> the same API and aims to be a drop-in replacement for touchables
> available in React Native.

https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-gesture-handler/docs/api/components/touchables/

You can install this library from:
https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-gesture-handler

Answer (score -1):

It might be because of the wrong import statement for the TouchableWithoutFeedback.

**Incorrect:**
`import { TouchableWithoutFeedback } from 'react-native'`

**Correct:**
`import { TouchableWithoutFeedback } from 'react-native-gesture-handler'`