# React.Children.only expected to receive a single React element child error

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, create-react-app

I'm getting 'React.Children.only expected to receive a single React element child.' from the following code.

I have created a new react app using create-react-app and installed redux and react-redux, and created a simple reducer and creating store with that.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { createStore, combineReducers } from "redux";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";

import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h2>Welcome to React</h2>
        </div>
        <p className="App-intro">
          To get started, edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}


function productReducer(state = [], action) {
  return state;
}

const store = createStore(
  productReducer
);

ReactDOM.render((<Provider store={store}><App /> </Provider>), document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: refer this link -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39862145/react-children-only-expected-to-receive-a-single-react-element-child-error-whe

Comment: provider expects a store and single root element.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You have a space here:

```
                               ↓
<Provider store={store}><App /> </Provider>
```

JSX is kinda picky about spacing on single lines. The above essentially gets interpreted as:

```
<Provider store={store}><App />{' '}</Provider>
```

(In fact, [Prettier](https://prettier.io/) will produce [pretty much this exact output](https://prettier.io/playground/#N4Igxg9gdgLgprEAuc0DOMAEBBADrzAXkwAoBKIgPlIB0oaYAeABQCcIA3ASwBM5XKjPAQD01RiLade-SnTIBuEABoQEXDC7pkoAIat2Ad2b6EaZCF0cIvFSABGrXWADWcGAGVczrlADmyDCsAK5wqgAWMAC2ADYA6uFc8GjeYHAeZklc3DAAnhZgaOaqvmj8MGy6flG6yABmujFlqgBWaAAeAEJOru4eulFwADK+cPWNzSBt7R6+fjFwAIrBEPDjTWEg3qxlrBb2uvZwMXa4rL4wcbww4cgAHAAMqmcQZXFOuBZncLscY6oARxW8CkuHMKF0aAAtFA4HA+Dw7Kw4ECuMjKtVakgGhtVGUolxAiFNmg5gtlqsxtiJpsYIcrjwbsgAEyqIK6LgxOYAYQgURqFig0H+IGCZQAKodwTiygBfWVAA))

You can either remove the space:

```
<Provider store={store}><App /></Provider>
```

Or break it up on to multiple lines:

```
<Provider store={store}>
    <App />
</Provider>
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked, but how to troubleshoot this kind of problems?

Comment: Thanks, to me it helped to remove one extra comma(,).

Comment: For me it was an extra semicolon inside the Formik arguments

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and it turns out I had converted my App root from a function to a class, which means I had to change the syntax from this:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    { App }
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

To this:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    { <App /> }
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```