# Not being able to render form using Formik and Material UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, formik

I am trying to use Formik and Material UI. This is a very basic example which am trying to work on. However, I am getting the following error: `React.Children.only expected to receive a single React element child.`

This error comes at the line where Formik begins,i.e. :

```
export default function sample() {
    const classes = useStyles({});
    const [sent, setSent] = React.useState(false);
    const handleSubmit = () => {
       console.log('done');
    };
return (
        <Row type="flex">
            <Typography variant="h3" >
                YO
               </Typography>
            <Typography variant="body2" align="center">
                YO YO
             </Typography>
            <Formik
                initialValues={{
                    fname: '',
                    lname: '',
               }}
                validationSchema={YOYOSCHEMA}
                onSubmit={handleSubmit}
            >
                {({ isSubmitting }) => (
                    <Form>
                        <Grid container spacing={2}>
                            <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
                                <Field
                                    autoFocus
                                    component={CustomTextField}
                                    autoComplete="fname"
                                    fullWidth
                                    label="First name"
                                    name="firstName"
                                    required
                                />
                            </Grid>
                            <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
                                <Field
                                    component={CustomTextField}
                                    autoComplete="lname"
                                    fullWidth
                                    label="Last name"
                                    name="lastName"
                                    required
                                />
                            </Grid>
                        </Grid>
</Form>
                )};
                </Formik>
        </Row >
    )
}
```

EDIT:
Here is the customtextfield code. Internally its using TextField of the Material UI:

```
 const CustomTextField = ({
        autoComplete,
        input,
        InputProps,
        meta: { touched, error, submitError },
        ...other
    }: { autoComplete: any, input: any, InputProps: any, meta: any }) => (
            <TextField
                error={Boolean(touched && (error || submitError))}
                {...input}
                {...other}
                InputProps={{
                    inputProps: {
                        autoComplete,
                    },
                    ...InputProps,
                }}
                helperText={touched ? error || submitError : ''}
            />
        );
```

I am using YUP for validation.
How to fix the error? Thanks.

Comment: Could you post the code for your ```CustomTextField``` component? The issue could be there, but at first glance everything looks in order with what you've posted.

Comment: @RutherfordWonkington Updated the question.

Comment: Try [removing unnecessary spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44937653/react-children-only-expected-to-receive-a-single-react-element-child-error).  The amount of whitespace you have around your ```Form``` closing tag could be causing JSX to miss it and believe you're not returning a single element inside of ```<Formik/>```.  Or there could be more spaces between elements somewhere else.  But you are (at least I think) returning only one element where that's required, so I'd definitely look into the formatting.

Comment: @RutherfordWonkington It didn't work.

Comment: Ah well.  I'd still run it through a code formatter if you can.  If you set it up in a Codesandbox I'll play around with it, but I could be missing something.