# CSSTransition and react-tabs, React.Children.only expected

Tags: css, reactjs, css-transitions, react-transition-group, react-tabs

I tried to make some animation to TabPanel, keeps sending me this error
(Error: React.Children.only expected to receive a single React element child.)
If i move the  oputside the Tabs it works otherwise it throughs the error

```
import React strong textfrom "react";
import {Tab, TabList, TabPanel, Tabs} from 'react-tabs';
import {CSSTransition} from 'react-transition-group';

function App() {
   return (
       <div>
        <Tabs>
         <TabList>
                <Tab>Overview</Tab>
                <Tab>Education</Tab>
            </TabList>
            <CSSTransition in={true}
                           apear={true}
                           timeout={50}
                           classNames="fade">
                <TabPanel>
                       <h1>Text 1 Here</h1>
                    </TabPanel>
                </CSSTransition>
               <TabPanel>
                   <h1>text 2 Here</h1>
               </TabPanel>
           </Tabs>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO! Great first question! Have you checked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39862145/react-children-only-expected-to-receive-a-single-react-element-child-error-whe or https://github.com/recharts/recharts/issues/935? :)